# delphi - watching for files changes in directories - implemented in JCL?

Tags: delphi, file, hook, jedi-code-library

I need to notify my application in some way whenever any file in the given directory has been changed (its content has been modified) ... is there any JCL/JVCL routine for that?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [TJvChangeNotify](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/unit.php?Id=3067) component located in JvChangeNotify.pas .

Bye.